# TypeScript: How to deal with generic types and the keyof operator

Tags: typescript, generics, generic-programming, keyof

I try to write a generic function which assembles update data for database updates.

Passed arguments:

- record to be updated
- property key
- a new array item

**Even though I restrict the key's type using `keyof R`, I cannot assign a new object with that key to a `Partial<R>` constant. I get the error `Type '{ [x: string]: any[]; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<R>'.`** What can I do to make the following code work? If I replace the generic type `R` by a non-generic type, it works. But this is not what I need.

[Snippet on TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20BaseRecord%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20readonly%20a%3A%20ReadonlyArray%3Cstring%3E%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20getUpdateData%3CR%20extends%20BaseRecord%3E(record%3A%20R%2C%20key%3A%20keyof%20R%2C%20newItem%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20updateData%3A%20Partial%3CR%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20%5Bkey%5D%3A%20%5B...record%5Bkey%5D%2C%20newItem%5D%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20updateData%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20DerivedRecord%20extends%20BaseRecord%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20readonly%20b%3A%20ReadonlyArray%3Cstring%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20readonly%20c%3A%20ReadonlyArray%3Cstring%3E%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aconst%20record%3A%20DerivedRecord%20%3D%20%7B%20a%3A%20%5B%5D%2C%20b%3A%20%5B%5D%2C%20c%3A%20%5B%5D%20%7D%0D%0AgetUpdateData%3CDerivedRecord%3E(record%2C%20%22c%22%2C%20%22first%20item%20in%20c%22))

```
interface BaseRecord {
    readonly a: ReadonlyArray<string>
}

function getUpdateData<R extends BaseRecord>(record: R, key: keyof R, newItem: string) {
    const updateData: Partial<R> = { [key]: [...record[key], newItem] }
    return updateData
}

interface DerivedRecord extends BaseRecord {
    readonly b: ReadonlyArray<string>
    readonly c: ReadonlyArray<string>
}
const record: DerivedRecord = { a: [], b: [], c: ["first item in c"] }
console.log(getUpdateData<DerivedRecord>(record, "c", "second item in c"))
```

Answer (score 19):

You can always bend the type system to your will, either through cunning (e.g., index access and the compiler assuming `R[key]` is read-write)

```
function getUpdateData<R extends BaseRecord>(record: R, key: keyof R, newItem: string) {
    var updateData: Partial<R> = {};
    updateData[key] = [...record[key], newItem]; 
    return updateData
}
```

or brute force (pass through `any` type):

```
function getUpdateData<R extends BaseRecord>(record: R, key: keyof R, newItem: string) {
    const updateData: Partial<R> = <any> { [key]: [...record[key], newItem] }
    return updateData
}
```

---

The above answers your question, but be careful: this function isn't safe.  It assumes any `record` passed in will have a `string[]` value for the `key` property, but the type `R` might not.  For example:

```
interface EvilRecord extends BaseRecord {
    e: number;
}
var evil: EvilRecord = { a: ['hey', 'you'], e: 42 };
getUpdateData(evil, 'e', 'kaboom');  // compiles okay but runtime error
```

Also, the return value type `Partial<R>` is a little too wide: you *know* it will have the `key` key, but you will need to check for it for the type system to be happy:

```
var updatedData = getUpdateData<DerivedRecord>(record, "c", "first item in c") // Partial<DerivedRecord>
updatedData.c[0] // warning, object is possibly undefined
```

I'd suggest typing `getUpdateData()` like this:

```
type KeyedRecord<K extends string> = {
    readonly [P in K]: ReadonlyArray<string>
};

function getUpdateData<K extends string, R extends KeyedRecord<K>=KeyedRecord<K>>(record: R, key: K, newItem: string) {
    return <KeyedRecord<K>> <any> {[key as string]:  [...record[key], newItem]};
}
```

(note this is still hard to type correctly because of [a bug in TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14473))  Now the function will only accept something where the `key` property is of type `ReadonlyArray<string>`, and guarantees that the `key` property is present in the return value:

```
var evil: EvilRecord = { a: ['hey', 'you'], e: 42 };
getUpdateData(evil, 'e', 'kaboom'); // error, number is not a string array

var updatedData = getUpdateData(record, "c", "first item in c") // KeyedRecord<"c">
updatedData.c[0] // no error
```

Hope that helps.

---

#### Technical Update

I changed the suggested `getUpdateData()` declaration above to have two generic parameters, because for some reason TypeScript was inferring a too-wide type for the `key` parameter before, forcing you to specify the key type at the call site:

```
declare function oldGetUpdateData<K extends string>(record: KeyedRecord<K>, key: K, newItem: string): KeyedRecord<K>;
oldGetUpdateData(record, "c", "first item in c"); // K inferred as 'a'|'b'|'c', despite the value of 'c'
oldGetUpdateData<'c'>(record, "c", "first item in c"); // okay now
```

By adding a second generic, I apparently delayed TypeScript's inference of the record type after it infers the key type correctly:

```
getUpdateData(record, "c", "hello"); // K inferred as 'c' now
```

Feel free to ignore this, but this is how sausage is made with heuristic type inference.

Answer (score 0):

Declaration of constant cannot be of type generic.

So your code changes will be

```
function getUpdateData<R extends BaseRecord>(record: R, key: keyof R, newItem: string) {
    const updateData:Partial<DerivedRecord> = {
        [key]: [...record[key], newItem]
    };
```

or

```
function getUpdateData<R extends BaseRecord>(record: R, key: keyof R, newItem: string) {
    const updateData = {
        [key]: [...record[key], newItem]
    };
```

or

```
function getUpdateData<R extends BaseRecord>(record: R, key: keyof R, newItem: string) {
   type PartRecord = Partial<DerivedRecord>;
   const updateData: PartRecord = {
    [key]: [...record[key], newItem]
};

return updateData;
}
```

Comment: I cannot mention the key `a` in the function because it might change outside.

Comment: @ideaboxer my bad forgot to remove it.  It will work event if `a` is not there also

Comment: Still I need to make sure `updateData` is of type `Partial<R>` because this constraint is a requirement for my return value. `DerivedRecord` may be any derivative of `BaseRecord`. Thus I cannot mention it in the function as you suggest.

Comment: I didnt understand can you elaborate?

Comment: You mention the interface name `DerivedRecord` in the function. But this makes nonsense of the generic type `R`. It is important for my use case that the function is generic. `DerivedRecord` may be replaced by `FolderRecord`, `UserRecord`, `LinkRecord` and so on.